# merge two datasets with datatable but keeping one of the identical column

Tags: r, data.table

Havent found this one yet so here we go.
I am using datatables and I want to merge two tables that differn in length.
Ich have done that successfully.

So basically I merge all rows where my key attribute "Name, Date1" from my table1 is euqal to my key attribute "Name, Date2" from my table 2.

The problem I got with this, that my Date2 from my table 2 disapperas.
I do not like that. I want to keep my date2 from my table 2.

Example:

Table1

```
Name   Date1
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      2018-01-03
```

Table2

```
Name   Date2
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      2018-01-15
```

Instead of looking like this in my

New table

```
Name   Date
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      NA
```

it should look like this

```
Name   Date1         Date2
A      2018-01-01    2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02    2018-01-02
A      NA            NA
```

Does anyone know the trick?

Comment: Consider `Date1` and `Date2` will be identical, could you just add `dt[, Date2 := Date1]` after `merge`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

The Date2 is not repeated in the output because it is used as a key and is essentially the same data when you are doing an equi-join. And since you are doing `all.x=TRUE`, it is a left join and only the left table (i.e. `ONE` is returned with any other non-key columns).

If you really want, you can duplicate the Date2 into Date1 and use Date1 for joining as follows:

```
TWO[, Date1:=Date2][ONE, on=.(Name, Date1)]
#   Name      Date2      Date1
#1:    A 2018-01-01 2018-01-01
#2:    A 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
#3:    A         NA 2018-01-03
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
ONE <- fread("Name   Date1
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      2018-01-03")
TWO <- fread("Name   Date2
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      2018-01-15")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `match`.  If you're dates are stored in a `POSIXct` variant or as strings, this should work as is:

```
t1 <- read.table(text = "Name   Date1
A      2018-01-01
  A      2018-01-02
  A      2018-01-03", header = TRUE)

t2 <- read.table(text = "Name   Date2
A      2018-01-01
A      2018-01-02
A      2018-01-15", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
t3 <- t1 %>%
  mutate(
    Date2 = t2$Date2[match(Date1, t2$Date2)], # this grabs Date2 from t2 only if the same Date appears in t1
    Date1 = ifelse(is.na(Date2), NA, Date1) # this sets Date1 to NA if Date2 is NA
  )
```

If you're dates are stored as factors, the code to set `Date1` to NA will need to be modified as follows (I didn't mess with dates, just left them as factors, so I needed this:

```
Date1 = ifelse(is.na(Date2), NA, as.character(Date1))
```

(note that this goes in the mutate statement, it doesn't stand alone)

### Edit

Here's a variant that does not use `mutate` that should work on `data.tables` - although I don't personally use `data.table`, so please test and confirm:

```
t3 <- with(t1, {
    Date2 <- t2$Date2[match(Date1, t2$Date2)] # this grabs Date2 from t2 only if the same Date appears in t1
    Date1 <- ifelse(is.na(Date2), NA, Date1) # this sets Date1 to NA if Date2 is NA
})
```

Comment: Since I haven't used data.tables, I can't answer that directly.  However, `match` is a base function, so that portion of the solution should be completely neutral to data.tables versus data.frames (or tibbles).  I can provide a variant that doesn't use `mutate` that should be completely safe no matter how you store the data (but test it and let me know).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sqldf` solution:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select a.Name, 
              case when b.Date2 is NULL 
                   then a.Date1 = NULL
                   else a.Date1 
              end as Date1 
              ,b.Date2 
      from df1 as a 
      left join df2 as b
      on a.Name = b.Name and
         a.Date1 = b.Date2')
```

**Result:**

```
  Name      Date1      Date2
1    A 2018-01-01 2018-01-01
2    A 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
3    A       <NA>       <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    Date1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", 
    "2018-01-03"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Date1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 = structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    Date2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", 
    "2018-01-15"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Date2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```